# JavaScript Promises and synchronous behaviour

Tags: javascript, promise, synchronous

I am trying to deserialise a JSON object which has a `type` key whose value is a string; if the type is "a", the object class is defined in "a.js" and this file contains an initialisation function `a_init`. There may be a `subobjects` key whose value is an array of objects. If so, these nested objects should be processed in the same way.

The code I have looks like this:

```
var files = [];

function load(obj) {
  if (!!obj["type"]) {
    let type       = obj.type;
    let subobjects = obj.subobjects;
    let promise    = new Promise(function(resolve) {
                         let script = document.createElement("script");
                         script.setAttribute("src", type + ".js");
                         script.addEventListener("load",resolve);
                         document.head.appendChild(script);
                     });
    promise.then(function() {
        if (!files.includes(type)) {
          files.push(type);
          if (subobjects instanceof Array) {
            for (element of subobjects) {
              load(element);
            }
          }
          let func = window[type + "_init"];
          if (typeof(func) =="function") {
            func(obj);
          }
        }
    });
  }
}
```

For an object like this:

```
{ "type": "a",
  "data": "foo",
  "subobjects": [
      { "type": "b",
        "data": "1"
      }
  ]
}
```

the output is:

```
This is A
This is B
```

(The functions `a_init` and `b_init` just display a message for testing purposes.)

My problem is that I would like the subobjects to be initialized before the outer object, so `b_init` would complete before `a_init` to give this output:

```
This is B
This is A
```

but of course the nested call to `load` just creates a new promise and then completes before the new promise does.

Is there any way to enforce synchronicity here to control the order of events?

Comment: If you only have one level of nesting, a simple solution could be to instantiate an empty promise, `let promise = new Promise();` and do your `.then`/`load` loop first, and then chain the `type` promise after that inside the function. You'll also need to return the promise from `load` so that the parent `load` can properly wait for it to resolve.

Comment: No, the nesting is unlimited. But it sounds promising (!) -- maybe I could put something in the x_init functions -- but I'm not completely clear what you're proposing; could you post some outline code to help me understand better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should convert your `load` function to `async` and inside it `await` for the promise and also for the recursive calls to finish.

```js
var files = [];

// using an async function here so that we can 
// use await inside it, but also so that we can
// await the whole function (it is recursively called
// and we want the recursions to fully complete before 
// continuing)
async function load(obj) {
  if (!!obj["type"]) {
    let type = obj.type;
    let subobjects = obj.subobjects;
    const promise = new Promise(function(resolve) {
      let script = document.createElement("script");
      script.setAttribute("src", type + ".js");
      script.addEventListener("load", resolve);
      document.head.appendChild(script);
    });
    
    await promise; // wait for the script to be loaded 
    
    if (!files.includes(type)) {
      files.push(type);
      if (subobjects instanceof Array) {
        for (element of subobjects) {
          // await for the nested object to completely run 
          // before continuing. This will go deep first

          await load(element);
        }
      }
      let func = window[type + "_init"];
      // we reach this place only after all nested objects
      // completed.
      if (typeof(func) == "function") {
        func(obj);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Aha, that works! Thank you. But I'm not sure I understand WHY it works...?

Comment: @user1636349 added some comments. We effectively have turned the whole flow to be synchronous. So, since you handle the nested objects first, before calling the current level `_init`, it will execute in "reverse" order.

Comment: Ah, got it. I hadn't noticed the use of "await" on the call to "load". Many thanks, again!